# Image binding from isolated storage?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, binding

I need some help to figure out why two different ways of binding an Image in XAML don't behave the same way.

Here is my code:

```
public class Picture 
    {

        public int ID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

public string ThumbURL
        {
            get
            {
                return String.Format("http://"+ App.ServerAdress +"/Pictures/thumbs/{0}.jpg", ID);
            }

        }

        public int ThumbLocal
        {
           get { return ID; }
        }
}

public class ByteImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {

           public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {


            using (var store =
               IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {


                if (!store.FileExists(value)) return null;

                var stream =
                    store.OpenFile(path, FileMode.Open);

                try
                {
                    var image = new BitmapImage();
                    image.SetSource(stream);
                    return image;
                }
                finally
                {
                    stream.Dispose();
                }
            }

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

In case I bind the image this way, it is working:

```
<Image  Width="110" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Source="{Binding ThumbURL}" 
                                    Margin="12,0,9,0"/>
```

But this way does not:

```
<Image  Width="110" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Source="{Binding ThumbLocal,  Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource imgConverter}}"  
                                        Margin="12,0,9,0"/>
```

This situation happens when I try to set picture from one panorama item to the other. I my case I want to add picture from one list to another and when I use first type of binding everything is working fine. Also it is working when I navigate to other page and navigate back, the picture shows up. I'm a little confused by this behavior.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

**Finally I realized why this happened. Before Binding I have to download picture from the web and save it to the Isolated Storage, all this process is async. And in time when I Bind the picture there in no picture yet. I have try to Bind existing picture from Isolated Storage and it is correctly displayed. So, now I need something like `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Is any way I can do it if I use `IValueConverter`?**

Comment: Where is it failing actually? There are plenty of places where you code might fail. * ThumbLocal propery might not exist on the binding source (you should not need Mode=TwoWay by the way) - then you should check your binding source. * ThumbLocal might not be set to a path of a file existing in isostore - you would need to check if it exists or not. * I can't see how value - an object type variable is used in FileExists that expects a string, but I assume you meant to cast it to a path string. * OpenFile might fail and you don't seem to be trying to catch it. * BitmapImage.DecodeFailed?

Comment: I have the same question,"Where is it failing actually?". Both code is "working", first one like I need, the second one is not. I know my English is not that good, but try to read one more time my question. How will you solve this use case where you need to Bind image from Isolated Storage but firstly you have to download this image and save to there(Isolated Storage)? You was right about FileExists I have change code little, in original I build the path with String.Format("{0}", ID). I think it is happen because I download the picture and save to IS async, so Binding don't see the picture.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "not working". Is it crashing or is the image simply not showing up? Did you try stepping through the converter in the debugger to see if "return image" was called?

Comment: I have edit my question, please read it one more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it so that if the image is not in isolated storage - you start downloading the image, but return a new BitmapImage immediately and only when downloading is complete - save the image to isostore and set it as the BitmapImage's source.

Something like:

```
if (!store.FileExists(value))
{
    var image = new BitmapImage();
    ImageDownloadAndCachingHelper.DownloadImage(path, (s, e) => image.SetSource(e.ImageStream));
    return image;
}
```

It is up to you to implement the code that converts the local path into a web URI, download it and invoke the EventHandler, where ImageDownloadedEventArgs has the ImageStream.

Comment: Hello, yours solution fine, but I am not that good to implement it. Because it all async to download and store do Isolated Storage. If you have time you can post rest of the solution in your answer. Any way, you give me idea to do it this way;                 `if (!store.FileExists(path)) return String.Format("http://"+ App.ServerAdress +"/Pictures/thumbs/{0}.jpg", value);` Thanks for help.

Comment: Your solution will work to get the image from a web address when it is not in isolated storage. If you want to save it to isolated storage when not there already - you would have to implement some caching solution and this is too custom to have someone else do it for you, since it really depends on why you would want these images in isolated storage. If you just use the URI - it is possible the web stack will silently cache it for you anyway.